# What are most hydrogen-dense materials that a pre-electric civilization could produce?

Tags: science-based, physics, chemistry, steampunk, industrial-age

## Context

My world has an 'unobtanium' strategic resource that is an alternate form of hydrogen. When atoms of this hydrogen is embedded in a rotor, they generate a field force that pushes against the surrounding matter. This is applied anywhere an 'ideal propeller' could be used with no moving parts exposed to the outside world: from ships and submarines without external propellers to flying cars and even flying battleships. The hydrogen is collected in the form of water vapour from volcanoes on geologic hot spots.

Aside from this force, it is chemically equivalent to hydrogen.

The world is also limited to technology that does not use electricity by a natural force for "the author likes Steampunk" reasons. So no electrolysis, and no cheap aluminum.

## Question

Given these tech limits, what 'general category' (like the category of 'hydrocarbons') of material would have very high hydrogen density that could be produced that would be good for building rotors and for storing strategic reserves of this stuff long-term, and what are some specific chemicals in these categories?

Here I define 'hydrogen density' as the quantity of hydrogen atoms per unit volume. It doesn't really matter what form it's in, as long as it can be contained and rotated around an axis.

My own research (ChatGPT + supplementary googling) has turned up metal hydrides, which in general seem to be manufacturable without electricity. If metal hydrides are the answer, I'd like to know which ones are best for a non-electric civilization.

## Secondary Question

Suppose the geopolitical distribution of unobtanium sources is very unequal, and unobtanium-rich countries highly restrict exports.

How could governments deliberately tamper with black-market exports to interfere with importers' use of it? If the raw condensed water vapor is exported, what additives could interfere with refinement, and if its refined form for use in rotors is exported, what additives could cause it to decay and release the unobtanium-hydrogen, spontaneously combust, or otherwise be rendered useless or harmful over time?

My own research (same approach as above) suggested adding oxidizers to the metal hydrides, though I question how feasible that would be to induce a delayed reaction. Sabotage is best when it's discovered at the most inconvenient time, after all.

Comment: ice and oils are all hydrogen dense, do you need the hydrogen in a particular form? are you measuring density by mass or number of atoms?

Comment: Margarine?  Seriously though, if you've heard about "saturated" and "unsaturated" fats, the big difference is that one's just had all it's spare carbon - carbon double bonds broken and additional hydrogen shoved in. One way to add the extra hydrogen is (more or less) to just bubble hydrogen gas through it... should be doable in a pre-electric civilisation

Comment: (a) You are allowed to ask one and only one question per post. It's literally a reason to close questions (VTC:Needs More Focus). (b) "Best" is always subjective. Best for what? Using today's technology, no single material or class of materials is "best" for making motor rotors and stators. Worse, you appear to be declaring the existence of a fictional non-magnetic magnetic motor - and you want it to be, what, scientifically accurate? (c) The [help/dont-ask] specifically forbids giving your own answer and asking for more. You're writing fiction. What's stopping you from using the hydrides?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the highest proportion of hydrogen by mass in a compound, you need to start by looking at the first two rows of the periodic table, because those give you the lightest atoms to combine with your hydrogen. You also need to consider the available technologies within your society.

- Hydrogen gas is inconvenient to handle, and liquid hydrogen is impractical at this tech level.
- Helium does not form compounds with hydrogen.
- Lithium and beryllium aren't readily available without electrolysis, and are very reactive. Beryllium is also *quite* toxic.
- Boron forms diborane, B2H6, which is a toxic pyrophoric gas. It has quite a good proportion of hydrogen, but it reacts violently with air and water, which makes it hard to handle.
- Carbon gives you methane, CH4. There's an excellent proportion of hydrogen,  but it's an inflammable gas. It isn't nearly as bad as diborane, but it isn't good.
- Nitrogen gives you ammonia, NH3. It's a gas that is smelly, inflammable if you work at it, and hazardous in high concentrations. A pre-electrical society will likely have to extract it from animals' waste products; you don't technically need electricity to run the [Haber Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process), but electrical equipment makes controlling the process far easier.
- Oxygen gives you water, H2O. This has a lot of advantages, being a  reasonably dense liquid, non-toxic, and easy to handle.
- Florine gives you hydrogen fluoride, HF. Don't go there. This is a really bad idea.
- Neon doesn't form compounds with hydrogen.

Water is by far the easiest compound to handle, and is 11.1% hydrogen. This is what your engineers will prefer.

Methane is next, and is 25% hydrogen. This is your high-performance option, if you can produce enough of it.

Hydrogen gas is the highest-performance option, *if* you can confine it under sufficient pressure to outperform water without adding so much weight that it makes thing worse.

Comment: Methane is 25% hydrogen. There are also more complex molecules of the same elements: butane is easier to keep liquid than methane but still gives you 20.8% hydrogen, and ethanol gives you a room temperature ambient-pressure liquid with 13% hydrogen. Borazine gives you a 20% hydrogen solid.

Comment: How do you make Borazine solid?

Comment: Sorry, meant borazane, or "ammonia borane". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia_borane

Answer (score 3):

Plastic contains tons of hydrogen. Polyethylene in particular, there is more hydrogen than in water.

But "science based" and "alternate form of hydrogen" don't mix well. Hydrogen is a very simple and basic element, if you modify it you get weird things like alternative form of water and of pretty much every single organic compound. It very likely makes life impossible.

Just make yourself an unobtanium out of some rare heavy element. Let's say, this universe has very similar but slightly different physics - different basic constants. It is theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen itself was generated prior to the use of electricity in the 16th and 17th centuries by the addition of iron or zinc to sulphuric acid. That would be 100% hydrogen but as a gas it would not be very dense. It would be very difficult to pressurise hydrogen sufficiently to create a high density using pre-electric technology. Especially if also considering the mass of the container.

The two best potential candidates for the most concentrated content of hydrogen in a given volume are water (11% hydrogen) and ammonia (21% hydrogen).

Ammonia has been known since antiquity and can be produced from the fermentation of urine, leaving ammonia solution. It can also be produced by other pre electric  methods.

The densest hydrogen containing material would have been concentrated ammonia solution with roughly 15% hydrogen content.